# Why do they say the PNT wasn't proven until Hadamard?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

I've been working my way through the MIT OCW course on number theory, and [the lecture on the PNT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-785-number-theory-i-fall-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_785F15_Lec15.pdf) states:

> However it was not until a century later that the prime number theorem was independently proved by Hadamard and de la Vallée Poussin in 1896, building on the work of Riemann, who in 1860 showed that there is a precise connection between the zeros of ζ(s) and the distribution of primes (we shall say more about this later), but was unable to prove the prime number theorem.

The paper cited of Riemann's is of course [this one](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/EZeta.pdf), which builds to the conclusion that the empirically known approximation $\pi(n) \sim \mathrm{Li}(n)$ has an error of $\mathrm{O}(\sqrt{n})$.  Now, the presentation is a little sketchy, but I don't see any step that isn't justified, so I was wondering - why is that not considered a proof?

Comment: Riemann's paper is a fantastic work of mathematics, but he was quite clear about the fact that there were several yet-unjustified assertions. Given those assertions, yes, the PNT follows; but those assertions (one of which is the Riemann hypothesis!) needed forty years or so of subsequent work.

Comment: My opinion : It was a huge mess until the 1st proofs of the prime number theorem. Dirichlet claimed a proof. Mertens and Chebyshev too, but they didn't look enough at the analytic properties of $\zeta(s)$ (its zeros). Riemann was interested by many other things and didn't care so much of $\zeta(s)$, even less of the prime number theorem (he was proud enough of his explicit formula). Finally (only 30yrs later) Hadamard and De laValléePoussin understood that a zero-free region together with the asymptotic number of zeros in Riemann's formula could lead to a **rigorous** proof, and published one.

Comment: @GregMartin, where exactly?  It definitely doesn't seem to rely on the Riemann hypothesis, since Riemann uses its absence as justification for giving up on proving it.  Rather, the paper uses the Euler product to express $\log\zeta(s)$ in terms of the integral of a function of $\pi(s)$, uses a Fourier transform to move the integral to the other side, and the Weierstrass factorization of $\xi(s)$ to express the integral in terms that resolve to logarithmic integrals.  No obvious contingencies there...

Answer (score 0):

Anyhoo, I myself am responding to this because I realized the answer, and no one made it all that clear in the comment thread, or answered at all.  Although Riemann dismissed his infamous hypothesis at the beginning, he quietly reintroduced it at the end in assuming that the $\alpha$ in $\sum^\alpha\frac{\cos(\alpha\log x)x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\log x}$ is real.

Comment: [Riemann showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula) that If $\zeta(s)$ has a zero on $Re(s) = 1$ then the PNT is false. But he didn't prove [$\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(s) = 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch), and by an approximate inverse Mellin transform this is enough to prove the PNT (Hadamard and De la Vallée Poussin's theorem)

Comment: Also the most general and modern way to prove the PNT is with this [Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem) about Dirichlet series with positive coefficients ($-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$)